# Get object info on click

Tags: knockout.js

How do I get the value of an object when I click on it from a list?

HTML Here:

```
<table class="ui table">

        <thead>
        <th class="header small">Operator:</th>
        <th>Employee ID:</th>
        <th>Category:</th>
        <th>Number:</th>
        <th>Team Group</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Operators, click: getopid">

    <tr>

        <td data-bind="text: lastfullname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: emp_number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: team"></td>
        <td><i class="icon trash"></i></td>
        <td><i class="icon edit"></i></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

now I want a click event on the list so it returns the userid only when someone clicks on the user's name in the list.

Here is my viewmodel:

```
function AppViewModel() {

self.editop = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Operators = ko.observableArray([]);
//fn Gets JSON data
this.GetData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "opControl.php",
        data: {action: "all"},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var mappedOp = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Opdata(item) });
            self.Operators(mappedOp);
        }, //end success
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR + errorThrown + textStatus);
        }
    }); //end $.ajax
};
//get operator list now
this.GetData();


this.getopid = function (event,data) {
    alert(event.target);
}




}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I had it working before with something similar to the above function, but I can't remember how I got it to work.

Comment: Where's your viewmodel? How are you bindings declared? How are you attaching the event handler?

Comment: Also see the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) in particular **Note 1: Passing a “current item” as a parameter to your handler function**

Comment: Ok, sorry I posted my full code now.  This should make some more sense.

Comment: As per the docs, the first argument to your `getopid` handler should be the view model. What are you actually seeing in your `getopid` handler? What arguments are being passed to it?

Comment: You are actually wrong about arguments in `getopid` first argument is data and second argument is event. Please see docs http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put your click binding inside the `foreach` (at the row) and the first parameter to the click handler will be the row data.

```js
function AppViewModel() {

  self.editop = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.Operators = ko.observableArray([]);
  //fn Gets JSON data
  this.GetData = function() {
    /*
    $.ajax({
      url: "opControl.php",
      data: {
        action: "all"
      },
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var mappedOp = $.map(data, function(item) {
          return new Opdata(item)
        });
        self.Operators(mappedOp);
      }, //end success
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + errorThrown + textStatus);
      }
    }); //end $.ajax
    */
    self.Operators([{
      lastfullname: 'LFN',
      emp_number: 1,
      category: 'Cat',
      number: 5,
      team: 'Team Cat'
    }]);
  };
  //get operator list now
  this.GetData();


  this.getopid = function(data, event) {
    console.debug(arguments);
    alert(data.lastfullname);
  }




}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table class="ui table">

  <thead>
    <th class="header small">Operator:</th>
    <th>Employee ID:</th>
    <th>Category:</th>
    <th>Number:</th>
    <th>Team Group</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Operators">

    <tr data-bind="click: $parent.getopid">

      <td data-bind="text: lastfullname"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: emp_number"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: team"></td>
      <td><i class="icon trash"></i>
      </td>
      <td><i class="icon edit"></i>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is declared at root level and you are inside a foreach statement, you need to use `$root` keyword to reference it. Like this:

**Note:** the click function should be declared in a `TR` not a `TBODY`

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Operators">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.getopid">
        <td data-bind="text: lastfullname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: emp_number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: number"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: team"></td>
        <td><i class="icon trash"></i></td>
        <td><i class="icon edit"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In your javascript just put a parameter in your function, like this:

```
function AppViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.Operators = ko.observableArray([]);
   //...
   self.getopid = function (op) {
      alert(op.lastfullname);
   };
};
```

Answer (score -2):

This should give an onclick function to each of the cells in your table. If the cell is clicked it will output the value to the console. Hope this helps.

```
var table = document.getElementById('yourTable'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    cells[i].onclick = function(){
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
        /*You can change this part to your desired output*/
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might be a solution if you write your own custom binding it is totaly not the way in viewModel. Why:
1) Are elements currently rendered already, is knockout changing things at the moment? No way to know, only binding are provided with such info.
2) When elements are removed you did not remove the event handlers
3) When new elements are added you did not add new events handlers
4) And last but not least I don't want to know heck about layout in my viewmodel.